# Connect to database with Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, sql-workbench-j

Trying to do something really simple, not sure why it's not working.

I downloaded SQL workbench and connected to my Redshift driver. Connection is fine. I created a database using `CREATE DATABASE dbexample`

Now I'm trying to connect to the database. I've tried `\c dbexample` and `\connect dbexample` and am getting the following error:

```
An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
\connect dbname

[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "\" 
Position: 1;

\connect dbname
^
1 statement failed.
```

Anyone know why it's not connecting?

Comment: It clearly says : syntax error at or near "\" Position: 1; that means you have an issue with your query...

Comment: do you know what query to use to connect to a database in postgresql? All the tutorials I can find say \c or \connect dbname is how you connect.

Comment: Workbench is working fine .... "Now I'm trying to connect to the database. I've tried \c dbexample and \connect dbexample and am getting the following error; " from where you trying this ?

Comment: I created the database in workbench by querying CREATE DATABASE dbexample. It says Database dbexample created

Execution time: 0.23s, now the tutorial tells me to connect to this database by querying \c dbexample. I get the error message when I try this

Comment: share ur tutorial link

Answer (score 0):

The `\backslash` commands are specific to the `psql` utility and are not generic SQL commands for use in a product such as SQL Workbench.

Instead, specify the database name when you connect SQL Workbench to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Provide the name of the database in the URL itself:

[image]